# Sending string array as response using DRF

Tags: arrays, string, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and I want to send a string array as response as follows:

```
['data2','data3']
```

These data are dynamically generated from the model where only values are selected corresponsing to key `'field1'` with a filter criterion `'field3'='type1'`
If following is the data I've in my model:

```
[{
'field1':'data1',
'field2':'nodata1',
'field3':'type2'
},
{
'field1':'data2',
'field2':'nodata2'
'field3':'type1'
},
{
'field1':'data3',
'field2':'nodata3',
'field3':'type1'
}]
```

I've tried with Response(). And using that I could able to send a string but not an array.

NB: I don't want to generate a JSON reponse as shown below.

```
    [{
        "field1": "data2"
    },
    {
        "field1": "data3"
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer:

You can achieve this by using the base APIView class. Below is the sample code:

1. views.py:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Label

class LabelList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        response = []
        labels = Label.objects.all()
        response = [label.field1 for label in labels]
        return Response(response)
```

------------Old Answer-------------

Use [generics.ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) to provide the data in an array and use serializer to only have field1.

Let see the sample code.

1. views.py:

```
# I am assuming your data to be a label, you can use any name for the class.
class LabelList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = LabelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # For perform any filters based upon loggedin user
        return Label.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

2. serializers.py:

```
class LabelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Label
        fields = [
            'field1',
        ]
```

Comment: I'm getting response as shown below which is not the required one.

        [{
            "field1": "data2"
        },
        {
            "field1": "data3"
        }]

I've edited my question for better understanding.

Comment: Hi Salah, I have updated my code. This will resolve your query.

Comment: Thanks, it's working!! Can I show only distinct values out of it? labels = Label.objects.values('field1').distinct() is not working here